# 4 RFID with Arduino Uno / add or remove card with master card /

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

i am new in coding for arduino. I need some help with the project i'm working on. my project is a object tracking by using the rfid rc522 for inventory system. so i need to have multi reader in this project. i would like to have 4 reder that will work at the same time.
this is how i want my project to work:
1. there is going to be 3 or 4 reader rc522, 1 i2s lec and leds.
2. one rfid tag will be use as the master card. the master card have the ability to add or remove card.
3. when 1 tag is tapped on 1 reader, the card quantity at the reader that it tapped will increase. example when we tap the tag at reader1, reader1 will add 1 card into its memory.

https://github.com/TasmanianDevilYouTube/Arduino/blob/master/RFID_master_slave_cards/RFID_master_slave_cards.ino

Comment: And what exactly is your problem with that? You didn't ask a question

Comment: what do you need help with ... right now, your post is like `I'm new to house building and I need some help with a project.  I'm building a house with 3 bedrooms and a basement suite.`

Comment: i want to have this coding to work with 4 rfid reader connected to arduino uno.

Comment: my bad. so do u know how to interface 4 rfid rc522 reader with arduino uno with the code in the link?

Comment: Still it is not clear, what your problem is. You need to narrow down the problem more. You already have a big code, which uses the `MFRC522` library to interface with the RFID reader. Is that working? If not: How exactly is it not working? What did you expect and what actually happens? Are the examples working, that normally come with such a library? Or is the problem, that you don't know how to extent the code?

Comment: my problem is i dont know how to modified this code so it will work on 4 rfid reader with exactly the same as the code is now. the code here is working fine with only 1 reader. i wanted to extend it to 4 reader. so how should i do the modification on the code?

Comment: are you able to interface 4 rfid readers with Arduino UNO? .... start with simple code that reads a card on any of the four readers .... if it is not possible to use 4 rfid readers with the UNO, then it is pointless to waste time trying to modify your code

Comment: yess im able to interface 4 rfid with arduino uno.

Comment: that why I m now trying to do it